# Object of a class inside another class

Tags: php, oop

```
class date{
    public $now,$today;
    public function __construct(){
        $now = new DateTime("now");
        $today = new DateTime("today");
    }
}

$date= new date();
echo $date->$now->format('l, jS F Y, g:i A');
```

The code is not working with error

> Notice: Undefined property: date::$now

As per OOP concept i need to declare `$now` and `$today` inside the class outside any function. but php doesn't need declaration of variables.

What's the correct method?

Comment: Please read the PHP manual's page on [properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php), as it covers the proper syntax for property access (which will correct both errors in the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring now and today as local variables to the constructor function, not instance variables of the class. You need to then reference them using $this

```
class date{
    public $now;
    public $today;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->now = new DateTime("now");
        $this->today = new DateTime("today");
    }
}
```

You might also want to rename that class so it's not confused with the built in date method.

Comment: Rename the class. I think php is confusing it for the date built n function

Comment: This answer, though useful, doesn't actually address the error which is caused by `$date->$now`; your answer coupled with the correct syntax of `$date->now->format(...)` fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have the correct form of OOP in php:

```
<?php
class date{
        public $now;
        public $today;

        public function __construct(){
                $this->now = new DateTime("now");
                $this->today = new DateTime("today");
        }
}

$date= new date();
echo $date->now->format('l, jS F Y, g:i A');
?>
```